# Cannot invoke 'sizeof' with an argument list of type '([Double])'

Tags: swift

I got this error message when invoke `sizeof`.

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/ViewController.swift:46:58: Cannot invoke 'sizeof' with an argument list of type '([Double])'

My code

```
let wts: [Double]  = [ -30 , 20 , 20 ]
let weights: NSData = NSData(bytes: wts, length: sizeof(wts))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem as in C with sizeof (double*) which doesn't return what you that it would return, except that Swift thankfully refuses to do it.

Comment: I'm also using withUnsafeMutablePointer() but not successful ..

Comment: What about using `count`?

Comment: count? what do you mean count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `sizeof()` on an instance, it expects a type. Use `sizeofValue()` instead.

```
let wts: [Double] = [-30, 20, 20]
let weights = NSData(bytes: wts, length: sizeofValue(wts) * wts.count)
```

Note that you need to multiply the sizeofValue's value by the count of the array, since it will return the size of each element in the array and not the size of the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the total byte size of your array, you need to know how many elements, and multiply that by the sizeof a double.

```
let wts: [Double] = [-30, 20, 20]
let sizeOfArray = wts.count * sizeof(Double) //sizeof requires a Type [Double] is not a type
let weights: NSData = NSData(bytes: wts, length: sizeOfArray
```